# How to add suggestionItems template to programmatically created sap.m.Input

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I've created this `sap.m.Input` and i need to add the suggestionItems-template programmatically:

```
var oInput = new sap.m.Input({
  value: "{Username}",
  visible: {
    path: 'AddVisibleFlag',
    formatter: function(value) {
      return value === "TRUE";
    }
  },
  showSuggestion: true,
  suggest: function(oEvent) {
    //do something here
  },
  suggestionItems: "{/UserSrchHlpSet}",
  // Here i need to add this programmatically:
  //<suggestionItems>
  //<core:Item text="{Username}" />
  //</suggestionItems>
})
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a list of suggestion items to the input using `addSuggestionItem` function. A solution can be reading the set `/UserSrchHlpSet` and for each element of the set to create a new `core:Item` with the corresponding `Username` as text (oCurrentItem). Then you add the item to the input:

```
oInput.addSuggestionItem(oCurrentItem);
```

Comment: Hm, the control is still missing the template for the suggestionItems, not the items itself. I'm still facing this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing template or factory function for aggregation suggestionItems of Element sap.m.Input#addInput !`

Comment: I found solution for the error. SuggestionItems and its template have to be added in this way:
`var oInput = new sap.m.Input({
showSuggestion: true,
suggestionItems: {
path: "/UserSrchHlpSet",
template: new sap.ui.core.Item({
text: "Username"
})
}
})`
suggest-function has to be implemented too.